# В 1С:Предприятие 8.3 как выйти из режима конфигуратор и предприятие в режим выбора информационной базы (чтобы выбрать другую базу)?

Tags: 1с

В 1С:Предприятие 8.3 как выйти из режима `конфигуратор` и `предприятие` в режим выбора `информационной базы` (чтобы выбрать другую базу)?

Answer (score 0):

Закрыть и запустить заново. Нет способа потому, что выбор ИБ, конфигуратор и предприятие это три разные программы.

1cv8s.exe - выбор ИБ

1cv8.exe - конфигуратор

1cv8c.exe - предприятие

Первая запускает вторую или третью и закрывается.